# How to collect characters in C?

Tags: c, string

I want to collect all alphabets from a string like `a,c,e,f`and put them in another string `acef`. I got a messed up result, `acef■   ┌sa,c,e,f`. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i,j=0;
    char str[10];
    strcpy(str,"a,c,e,f");
    char tmp[10];
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++) {
        if(str[i]==',') {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            tmp[j++]=str[i];
       }
    }
    printf(" %s",tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need null-terminator. E.g `tmp[j] = '\0';` after for-loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ,Thanks. You're a genius.

Comment: Also note `0` is equivalent to nul-character `'\0'`, so `tmp[j] = 0;` is fine. Also if you initialize `char tmp[10] = "";` you will fill the array with `0` before you begin... (you just must insure you don't write more than `9` chars, e.g. for `(i=0; i + 1 < 10 && i < strlen (str); i++)` (note: you should declare `int len = (int)strlen(str);` before the loop, and use `len` as the limit, so `strlen` isn't called more than once `:)`

Answer (score 4):

`char tmp[10]; ... printf(" %s",tmp);` lacked a certain *null character*.

You need null-terminator.

```
tmp[j] = '\0'; // after for-loop.
```

[@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579850/how-to-collect-characters-in-c#comment76148300_44579850)

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your `char tmp[10]` with 0,

```
char tmp[10];
memset(temp, 0, 10);
```

Comment: Alternatively: `char tmp[10] = {0};`